# Не могу подключиться к БД PostgreSQL используя property файл в JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Пытаюсь написать очень простое CRUD приложение, используя Spring и JDBCTemplate.
В принципе все работало, пока не попытался перенести конфигурацию БД во внешний файл

Создал такой файл database.properties

```
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/first_db
username=postgres
password=postgres
```

Файл конфигурации спринга выглядит вот так

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("cz.nowhale")
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext, Environment environment) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("driver")));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
}
```

добавил только аннотацию PropertySource, импортировал интерфейс Environment и в методе dataSource сделал ссылки на проперти из файла.
Но при запуске на локале выдает ошибку:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: 
Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ВАЖНО: пользователь "gross" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)
```

Сначала в конце этого сообщения еще писало, что есть проблема с кодировкой, что на сервере win-1251. Поменяв кодировку везде, где только можно, сообщение сократилось до такого варианта.
Самое непонятное, почему пишет пользователь gross. Это имя пользователя на моем компьютере. Имя пользователя в ДБ - postgres.
username и password в проперти файл 100% верные. Использую Intellij Idea, к дб имею доступ без проблем напрямую, только через браузер выбивает такую ошибку.

Comment: А в '@PropertySource' classpath верный? Может, что-то типа PropertySource("classpath:/com/site/database.properties")?

Comment: да, верный. Среда разработки подсвечивает, если не будет файла. Да и проперти, пока их не укажешь в datasource подсвечиваются в файле серым.  Вдобавок попробовал указать неверные данные в пропертях. При изменении url, usename и password выкидывается такая же ошибка. Но если изменить драйвер, то тоже 500, но с другим текстом

Answer (score 0):

В database.properties измени имя ключа username на что-нибудь другое, например на user_name. И в файле конфигурации соответственно тоже.
По умолчанию username тянется из имени пользователя Windows.